# How do I alias_method with ActiveSupport::Concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm trying to roll my own archiving in rails, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to alias the old `destroy` method before overriding it. Below is what I would like to do, but I get a `NoMethodError` because `destroy` isn't defined before that in the module. It works the way I'd expect if I put it in an `InstanceMethods` module, but that appears to be deprecated. Should I just handle it with a vanilla module or is there a way to do it with `ActiveSupport::Concern`?

```
module Trashable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope where(deleted_at: nil)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def deleted
      self.unscoped.where(self.arel_table[:deleted_at].not_eq(nil))
    end
  end

  alias_method :destroy!, :destroy

  def destroy
    run_callbacks(:destroy) do
      update_column(:deleted_at, Time.now)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @BenediktB, here is our latest version: https://gist.github.com/mockdeep/7574103

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a couple of things.

1 - destroy indeed does not exist **in the class where you include your module** before you include your module.

The long story is that the destroy method is probably generated and included for you by your ORM gem.

You can use ruby 2+ [prepend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html) to make sure your module appears after all the methods are there.

2 - You can use a vanilla module or an `ActiveSupport::Concern` as long as you get what you want and know what you are doing.

The point of `ActiveSupport::Concern` is mostly to manage modules hierarchies. If you have one level, I see no point in using it. I think mixing `prepend` with `ActiveSupport::Concern` is not a good idea.

(And after all, `ActiveSupport::Concern` is just plain vanilla modules in the end.)

3 - The recommended way to override a method while keeping the old is to use [alias_method_chain](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain).

You will then have a destroy_without_archive method available which will be the old way of doing it (before you overrode it).